# Result about upper triangular matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm looking for a result in linear algebra along the following lines.

> Let A be an $n\times n$ matrix, and suppose that for all $k\ge 1$, the diagonal entries of $A^k$ are all zero. Then, by possibly permuting (or changing?) the coordinates, $A$ is upper triangular.

Is there a known (maybe famous) result similar to the above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not true. Consider
$$
A=\pmatrix{0&0&1&-1\\ 0&0&1&-1\\ 1&-1&0&0\\ 1&-1&0&0}.
$$
View $A$ as the adjacency matrix of a (possibly negatively) weighted digraph, in a way that there is a directed edge joining node $i$ to node $j$ if and only if $a_{ij}\ne0$. Then the graph of $A$ is strongly connected. Hence $A$ is irreducible. In particular, $P^TAP$ is not triangular for any permutation matrix $P$.

However, since $A^2=0$, the diagonal of $A^k$ is zero for every $k\ge1$.

Comment: Very nice, thank you. Is the question still true if the entries of the matrix are nonnegative?

Comment: @geodude Yes. If $A$ is nonnegative and $A^k$ always has a zero diagonal, then the graph of $A$ contains no cycle. Therefore the first node of the longest path in the graph must be unreachable. Hence the first column of $P^TAP$ is zero for some permutation matrix $P$. Let $P^TAP=\pmatrix{0&\ast\\ 0&B}$ where $B$ is $(n-1)\times(n-1)$. Repeat the argument for $B$ and so on, we see that $A$ is similar via some permutation to a *strictly* upper triangular matrix.

Comment: thank you, that's exactly the result I'm looking for. Does this have a name, or where can this be found in context?

Comment: @geodude This result is too simple. I don't think it is a named theorem and I am not aware of any book that mentions it. Sorry.